# Why I am facing an error in moving object detection using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, imutils

I am using VS code as a IDE for writing my code for Moving object detection using Opencv python but I have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\Python programming\Moving_Object_detection.py", line 13, in 
    img = imutils.resize(img, width=500)
  File "D:\Python Vscode\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So can you give me the solution for it. I am providing you my code

```py
import cv2
import time
import imutils

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
time.sleep(1)

firstFrame = None
area = 500
# count = 0

while True:
    _, img = cam.read()
    text = "Normal"
    img = imutils.resize(img, width=500, height=500)
    grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gaussianImg = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayImg, (21, 21), 0)
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gaussianImg
        continue
    imgDiff = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gaussianImg)
    threshImg = cv2.threshold(imgDiff, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    threshImg = cv2.dilate(threshImg, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(threshImg.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    for c in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < area:
            continue
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # count = count +  1
        text = "Moving Object detected"
    print(text)
    cv2.putText(img, text, (10, 20),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("cameraFeed", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: welcome. please review [ask] and [mre]. you're expected to debug your code, not just dump it here. show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your issue is that openCV can't read you webcam either the index of your webcam might be wrong or it doesn't have permission to view your webcam.  If you still need some more help here is a link to open CVs guide to resolving none type issues.

A page on resolving none type errors
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/26/opencv-resolving-nonetype-errors/

Comment: that's not an "OpenCV" page. that's someone's blog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer my problem is been solved.

Answer (score 0):

first, that is bad practice to read frames like you do. there is a purpose for the other return value from the cam.read().

```py
success, cv_img = cam.read()
if success:
   # do whatever
else:
   print('capturing failed')
```

second, if as mentioned, this is a camera issue, try disabling the anti virus. I saw several of times that the cam wouldn't open because it was blocked by the anti virus.